# I'm getting ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT error while using vue.js, vuetify & firebase

Tags: firebase, vue.js, vuetify.js

I've recently been getting this error when my application is running:

sockjs.js?9be2:1609 GET http://192.168.0.41:8080/sockjs-node/info?t=1621413172231 net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

I've looked at some questions on here and tried to fix it myself but still getting the same error.

My vue.config.js file looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  transpileDependencies: [
    'vuetify'
  ],
  devServer: {

    proxy: 'http://localhost:8080/'
  }
}
```

Any ideas on how to help with this? Cheers

Comment: So you can access your application? Can you elaborate a bit more on what exactly is not working and what kind of environment you are using? And has anything changed recently since you started getting the error?

Comment: Yes, everything in the application is working fine but this error has recently just appeared. I haven't added anything recently but when testing it this recently popped up. I'm codding using visual studio code but not sure on what environment I'm using. I'm only starting off with coding :)

Comment: my test environment on google firestore is now changed from in test to production, I don't know if that could be a cause